# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField2 - Manage padding

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

[padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxWdh.png)

[padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBKzu.png)

I have some issues with the padding using DropdownButtonFormField2 in Flutter.

Either I set

```
menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
),
```

but then I have too much padding in the FormField when the item is selected (see picture padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0)),

or I set

```
menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
),
```

but then the items in the dropdown list have no padding (see picture padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)).

I would like to have some left padding for the items in the dropdown list and no additional padding in the form field when the item is selected.

Full code:

```
DropdownButtonFormField2<String>(
  isDense: true,
  isExpanded: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: const Icon(
      Icons.transgender_outlined,
      color: Colors.white70,
    ),
    //     labelText: "Hello",
    //    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.9)),
    filled: true,
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize:16, color: Colors.white),
  ),
  hint: const Text(
    'Select Your Gender',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  items: genderItems
      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: item,
    child: Text(
      item,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
      ),
    ),
  ))
      .toList(),
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return 'Please select gender.';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedGender = value.toString();
    });
  },
  onSaved: (value) {
    _selectedGender = value.toString();
  },
  buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
  ),
  iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    iconSize: 24,
  ),
  dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
    offset: const Offset(0, -20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
    ),
  ),
  menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
  ),
),
```

I tried to combine padding for MenuItemStyleData, DropDownStyleData, and ButtonStyleData, with no luck.

Comment: This is surprisingly frustrating, the only way I can think of is to use `customButton` with `Transform.translate` and give it a negative offset

Comment: Spot on, “surprisingly frustrating” .. Even with the solution you propose, I think the padding of MenuItemStyleData (or DropDownStyleData) is passed to ButtonStyleData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've figured out, all of those style settings (`ButtonStyleData`, `DropdownStyleData`, `MenuItemStyleData`) affect both the dropdown menu item and the button display. There's a [`selectedMenuItemBuilder`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dropdown_button2/latest/dropdown_button2/MenuItemStyleData/selectedMenuItemBuilder.html) parameter in `MenuItemStyleData` but unfortunately this only affects selected item. So currently it seems like there is no way to achieve that by using proper padding options.

One way to achieve this is to let the `MenuItemStyleData` has some padding while providing a custom widget to the `customButton` parameter.

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField2<String>(
  // ...
  menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
  ),
  customButton: Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          _selectedGender.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image: Dropdown screenshot]

---

You can see a reference of how the default dropdown button is implemented in the source code ([dropdown_button2.dart#L727](https://github.com/AhmedLSayed9/dropdown_button2/blob/master/packages/dropdown_button2/lib/src/dropdown_button2.dart#L727)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Do you know why my Hint text disappears when I use Custombutton? It shows “null” before a value is selected.

Comment: Well, because this is totally customized, so you have to handle the logic for the hint text manually xD

Comment: Thanks! I‘m quite new at customizing widgets, can you maybe provide some hints where to start?

Comment: This is what I've done to add back the hint:

children: <Widget>[
                              if (_selectedGender == null)
                                Text(
                                  "Gender",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                )
                              else
                                Text(
                                  _selectedGender.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),